# Ideas for limited camera pan and tilt

Tags: camera, raspicam, servo

I have a number of Pis, each with a camera module attached.
I've mounted the cameras on a flat board side by side, but have discovered that there are physical inconsistencies in the camera modules manufacturing which cause them to point in slightly skewiff directions.
I'm looking for ideas of to programmatically correct this via some sort of electronically controlled platform/bracket which can physically adjust the direction that the camera is pointing.

I've seen that there a full pan/tilt servo controlled brackets, but I don't need a full range of motion. I'm looking for something simpler, as it should only require 5-10 degrees of pan and tilt at most, and the cheaper the better.
I'm thinking there might be something out there which uses four pistons(one on each corner of a panel) to adjust direction, but I've been unable to find anything.

Can someone point me in the right direction if they are aware of anything like this, or even if you have other ideas for solving my problem.

On another note, once I do get this working, can anyone suggest a software/scripting solution that will help me calibrate the direction of the camera, say by evaluating a physical marker in the camera'f field of view?

Thanks in advance.
Tim

Comment: If you forgo the multiple camera approach you could buy a pan and tilt mount and take multiple photos that could then be stitched together. If you really need the multiple cameras you will need to build  something that operates like a turnbuckle with very fine threads so you can make individual pan and tilt adjustments to each camera - obviously this is the much more difficult approach, and one that would require regular adjustments to compensate for wear, vibration etc. Another option is to solve the problem in software, You may lose some of each picture along the edges.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the project and its goal is. Are you looking to take panoramic pictures or macro photography?

Comment: If this is a one time thing its going to be hard to beat manual adjustment (screws, ball and socket, bendy metal).  For sonething electromechanical you can just use a reducing linkage - maybe a servo wheel cut along a spiral as a cam, or linkage from a normal servo wheel to the end of a long actuating lever.

Comment: Are you looking for a software solution to adjust the resultant images? if the angles are small enough and the data lose at the edges is acceptable.

Comment: You might want to look in the computer vision libraries (like CV) at image registration routines.  It might be appropriate for your needs: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/reg/doc/registration.html